# Decompiling Java: Using JD I get an empty enum class

Tags: java, enums, decompiling

I have decompiled a set of classes using JD.

In one of the classes there is a reference to a public field in a class. I open the class with the mentioned field. Imagine my surprise when I came across this:

```
public enum agw
{
}
```

I've come to the conclusion that the decompiler doesn't successfully decompile some kind of class type, possibly enums. I have come across a few of these.

Another example:

```
public enum acf
{
  private final Class d;
  private final int e;
  private final acn f;
  private final boolean g;

  private acf(Class paramacn, int paramBoolean, acn arg5, boolean arg6)
  {
    d = paramacn;
    e = paramBoolean;
    Object localObject;
    f = localObject;
    boolean bool;
    g = bool;
  }

  public Class a() {
    return d;
  }

  public int b() {
    return e;
  }

  public acn c() {
    return f;
  }

  public boolean d() {
    return g;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what these classes are supposed to be? What they could have represented in their original form?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the classes have been obfuscated, probably to avoid making any sense of them when decompiling them (which, BTW, is probably forbidden by the license). Another reason might be to make a jar smaller. Anyway, if you want to make sense of the source code, get the source code. If it's not available freely, it means you're not supposed to access it.

Comment: It could be that the enum values (public static fields) where unused and the obfuscator optimized them away. _As it would not be difficult to decompile the enum fields._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I believe this would actually be expected behavior because jad only supports (properly) Java versions up to 1.4. Enumerations were introduced in Java 1.5. This could explain things.

Answer (score 2):

I think the class you are trying to decompile is [obfuscated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29). Its clear from the code below:

```
private final Class d;
  private final int e;
  private final acn f;
  private final boolean g;

  private acf(Class paramacn, int paramBoolean, acn arg5, boolean arg6)
  {
    d = paramacn;
    e = paramBoolean;
    Object localObject;
    f = localObject;
    boolean bool;
    g = bool;
  }
```

- Programmers may deliberately obfuscate code to conceal its purpose (security through obscurity) or its logic to prevent tampering, deter reverse engineering, or as a puzzle or recreational challenge for someone reading the source code.

If you really want the access to the code, contact the owner. Otherwise, it is very difficult to understand the obfuscated code.

Answer (score 1):

While decompiling, you should use more than one decompiler. Decompiler A might successfull at doing something and decompiler B at another thing. So, using them together will help you to more easily complete the whole picture.

Comment: I will definitely give this a shot. :)